# parseInt(18446744073709551616) returning 18446744073709552000 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am parsing a string to an integer and it works fine until certain values. After that the result is not exact.
The code will be like below

```
parseInt(someString);//this string will have any value.
```

For example when i execute the below code i get result as **18446744073709552000**

```
parseInt(18446744073709551616) //result 18446744073709552000
```

But I am expecting the result to be 18446744073709551616.

Can any one tell what is wrong? And how do I accomplish what I want.

**I need to check if a string exceeds the maximum value or not. So how is that possible?**

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t

Comment: These questions do not answer my question of How I can check if a string exceeds the maximum integer value in javascript. That is the answer i am looking for. I have edited the question also accordingly.

Comment: If you need to do this you'll need to use a js library designed for large numbers like http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

Comment: @ckv: You didn't mention strings originally. The value you pass to `parseInt` is a number (because you are using a number literal). You might want to update your example.

Comment: @FelixKling: Updated the code and question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exceeding the `max value` of Integer in JavaScript, subsequently losing precision.

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

---

For the reason why you're getting zeroes:

> Let mathInt be the mathematical integer value that is represented by Z
>   in radix-R notation, using the letters A-Z and a-z for digits with
>   values 10 through 35. **(However, if R is 10 and Z contains more than 20
>   significant digits, every significant digit after the 20th may be
>   replaced by a 0 digit, at the option of the implementation; and if R
>   is not 2, 4, 8, 10, 16, or 32, then mathInt may be an
>   implementation-dependent approximation to the mathematical integer
>   value that is represented by Z in radix-R notation.)**

http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.1.2.2

Comment: Is'nt there anyway to make a this check whether it has exceeded the max value.

Comment: but shouldn't it throw an error instead of returning another value which is again bigger than the max value?

Comment: the javascript number type can exceed the maximum integer by converting to a double essentially. javascript uses the number type not integer or double or float. it is really it's own encapsulation and can vary between browsers.